# Não consigo centralizar o video

Tags: html, css3

Galera estou tentando centralizar o video, tentando usar o margin:0 auto; existe a possibilidade de eu posicionar através do padding ou algo assim,mais quando vou usar o box-shadow ele acaba pegando no padding também então prefiro não usar, fiz na outra pagina exatamente igual isso e foi normal, mais agora preciso colocar denovo e não vai, tem como me ajudar.

HTML

```
<div id="corpo">
      <h1>Seje Bem Vindo(A)</h1>
      <video controls>
          <source src="img/transpiedade.mp4">
      </video>            
</div>
```

CSS

```
#corpo video{
    width: 750px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O `margin: 0 auto;` só vai funcionar com elementos de bloco. Então basta adicionar `display: block;` na tag `video`:

```css
#corpo video{
    width: 750px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="corpo">
      <h1>Seje Bem Vindo(A)</h1>
      <video controls>
          <source src="img/transpiedade.mp4">
      </video>            
</div>
```

Comment: testei aqui, deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Blz.. Saiba como agradecer no [tour].